# Unable to create a new Cloud Function - cloud-client-api-gae

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I'm unable to create a Cloud Function in my GCP project using GUI, but have admin roles for GCF, SA and IAM.

Here is the error message:

> Missing necessary permission iam.serviceAccounts.actAs for
> cloud-client-api-gae on the service account
> serviceaccountname@DOMAIN.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Grant the role
> 'roles/iam.serviceAccountUser' to cloud-client-api-gae on the service
> account serviceaccountname@DOMAIN.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

`cloud-client-api-gae` is not an SA nor User on my IAM list. It must be a creature living underneath Graphical User Interfrace.

I have Enabled API for GCF, AppEngine and I have `Service Account Admin` role.

I had literally 0 search results when googling for `cloud-client-api-gae`.

Comment: Thanks for asking this! I'm running into the same exact issue and had no idea what needed to be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've contacted GCP support and it seems my user was missing single role:
`Service Account User` - that's it.

PS: Person from support didn't know what this thing called "cloud-client-api-gae" is.

Comment: Had the some problem, my error message was saying: cloud-boq-clientapi-functions. Also fixed it by giving my user account the role Service Account User on this specific service account.

Answer (score 2):

Saw the same thing.  You need Service account user on the SA you plan to deploy the CF onto.  The same incorrect identity was shown.

Answer (score 2):

The user account attempting to create cloud function, need to be given "Service account user" role on the Service account they are using for this cloud function to run on.